# Samba is not sharing NTFS filesystem folders. (Kubuntu 20.04)

Tags: networking, server, kubuntu, samba, 20.04

I've a dual boot setup Kubuntu 20.04 and Windows 10.
With Kubuntu 20.04 I'm trying to share some folders to my network via Lan/Wlan. So that I can easily access them from my Android and Windows machine. But I'm facing a problem.

When I'm sharing folders from my **/home** directory. It's working. But when I'm trying to share folders from **NTFS** drive.

Samba does not sharing those folders.

Here's my process:

1. Installed **samba**
2. Created a samba user by **sudo smbpasswd -a ishan** (ishan is the username)
3. Enabled samba with **sudo systemctl enable smbd nmbd**
4. Start samba by **sudo systemctl start smbd nmbd**
5. Then just goto **/mnt/media** and Right-Click to **Videos** folder then goto properties and share.
   [image]

But this Shared-Folder does not appearing to my network. When I try to access this machine from Windows and Android.

It only shows **print$** folder.

When I run **smbstatus**, that **video** folder is not showing in the list. Here **testparm -s** and **net usershare info --long** screenshots.

[image]

[image]

[image]

How to fix it ???

Comment: Please edit your original question and add the results of the following commands: `testparm -s` and `net usershare info --long`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.
Adding this line into the **[global]** section of this file **/etc/samba/smb.conf**  solved the problem.

```
usershare owner only = false
```

After adding this line the Samba worked perfectly.
But if you having problem by accessing from another machine. Then you also need to add this line to the **[global]** section of **/etc/samba/smb.conf**

```
client min protocol = NT1
```

or

```
client min protocol = CORE
```

So now it looks like this:
[image]

[image]